# Finding the maximum and minimum frequency of a 2D image

Tags: image-processing, fft, frequency-spectrum, frequency

Suppose I transform the image into frequency domain and obtain a 2D array of complex numbers. How can I determine the minimum and maximum frequency from that array? By finding magnitude of each complex number and then applying a search algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

I think our friends on Stackoverflow have [a solution for you that would be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777752/maximum-frequency-present-in-an-image-in-matlab). Despite this being MATLAB code, I believe the solution extends to a general answer to your question.